# Any good CSS Hack for fixing this issue with MudBlazor Multi-Select and Virtualize?

Tags: html, css, blazor, mudblazor

Basically, I'm using a MudBlazor MultiSelect field for a very large list.

However, it was really sluggish, obviously. Therefore, I tried to inject the Virtualize component into it, which worked for performance, with one caveat; it seems to create this huge space on the form underneath (probably depending on the size of the list it's trying to virtualise) :(

I've created a little snippet as an example here to work on. After finding a little autogenerated div is created, tried reducing the height of it in the browser, which works, but when I try to set it in the blazor page, it just makes the multi-select list really small as well. That's the limit of my HTML/CSS knowledge as to what's happening and if ther'es some hack to get around it?

Here is the snippet, if anyone can help please: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GEmxOHGicezopxcR

Comment: try this .mud-input-control-input-container label {
    background: brown;
    font-size: 2rem!important;
}

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You'll have to play around with the margins as it'll displace the MudSelect.

```
<style>
.select-wrapper {
margin:20px 20px;
position:relative;
max-height:50px;
}
.virtual-wrapper{
overflow-y:auto;
}
</style>

<div class="select-wrapper">
    <MudSelect T="string" Label="US States" MultiSelection="true" @bind-Value="value" @bind-SelectedValues="options">
        <div Class="virtual-wrapper">
            <Virtualize Items="@states" Context="state1" >
                <MudSelectItem T="string" Value="@state1">@state1</MudSelectItem>
            </Virtualize>
        </div>
    </MudSelect>
</div>
```

[mudblazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GuQHORGtYExavBhA)